# Push notification with Appcelerator (ACS) on Android

Tags: notifications, titanium, push, appcelerator

I'm trying to implement push notification with Appcelerator Cloud Service on Android But I have some issues ... tiapp.xml here :

```
<sdk-version>2.0.2.GA</sdk-version>
<modules>
<module platform="commonjs" version="2.0.5">ti.cloud</module>
<module platform="android" version="2.0.5">ti.cloudpush</module>
</modules>
```

Android runtime v8 and ti.cloudpush included, here is my app.js file

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
backgroundColor:'#ccc',
title:'Android Cloud Push Notification'
})

var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
CloudPush.debug = true;
CloudPush.enabled = true;
CloudPush.showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused = true;
CloudPush.focusAppOnPush = false;

var deviceToken;

var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');
Cloud.debug = true;

var submit = Ti.UI.createButton({
title : 'Register For Push Notification',
color:'#000',
height : 53,
width : 200,
top : 100,
});
win.add(submit);

submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
success: function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
alert('Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
deviceToken = e.deviceToken
loginDefault();
},
error: function deviceTokenError(e) {
alert('Failed to register for push! ' + e.error);
}
});
});

function defaultSubscribe(){
Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe({
channel: 'chanel',
device_token: deviceToken,
type: 'android'
}, function (e){
if (e.success) {
alert('Subscribed for Push Notification!');
}else{
alert('Error:' +((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
}
});
}

function loginDefault(e){
//Create a Default User in Cloud Console, and login
Cloud.Users.login({
login: 'android',
password: 'android'
}, function (e) {
if (e.success) {
alert("login success");
defaultSubscribe();
} else {
alert('Error: ' +((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
}
});
}

CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
//alert(evt);
alert(evt.payload);
});

CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickLaunchedApp', function (evt) {
//Ti.API.info('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running)');
alert('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running');
});

CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickFocusedApp', function (evt) {
//Ti.API.info('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
alert('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
});

win.open();
```

I had the user android / android in the Appcelerator cloud console for the development mode. Launched my app to my device with debogage mode
On the app : Just click on the button "register for push notification" and see 3 alerts 
1) Device Token : " all numbers " 
2) login success 
3) Subscribed for Push Notification!

On the Appcelerator Cloud console : 
Logs -> see login & subscribe, opened it and everything's ok 
Push Notifications -> 1 Android clients subscribed to push notifications. And send one throught push notifications with alert & title
And nothing appears at all ... try reboot, try to turn the app off and send another one, nothing.
I was using a device (LG OPTIMUS ONE) with android 2.2.1 with internet on it (wifi). So, I tried with another phone (SAMSUNG GALAXY S2) 3.3.2 with internet on it (wifi)
And the only change is in the cloud console : 
Push Notifications -> 2 Android clients subscribed to push notifications.
But it is the same, no notification appears.
Please, I really need help for this, I succeed with iOS in 2 days and I do not understand what is the big deal here ?

Comment: Check it out : https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/listing?q=PushClient I have created and published an Titanium Module to deal with Android (GCM) and iOS (APN) push notification.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I need to register with Google C2DM for using ACS. 
ACS use MQTT protocol for sending push.
(I followed this step by step tut : http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2012/06/appcelerator-cloud-push-notification-in.html)
Have you already done one project with push notification on Android & Ti ?
I checked my settings and everything is fine. 
But, because I'm desperate, I also register to C2DM and nothing better, I guess I have to wait a bit more before testing.

Answer (score 2):

I use the upush module in the Marketplace, took me 10 minutes to gtet it up and running, saved me loads of time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered with Google C2DM? You need to fill out the form at https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/signup to send notifications to the device. Make sure you have your correct App ID in the Appcelerator Cloud Settings.